# data reader specified cast is invalid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm using c# asp.net, just trying to display data in a read-only format once it's been submitted. It's for training, and my handler says no parameterizing, (it's not for actual deployment); when I run the select command, I throw the *specified cast is invalid* exception at the first GetInt32 line. The values are ints, and the columns are set up as ints. What am I missing?

```
string epl = "SELECT Entity, Employees, CA, MI, NY, NJ, Primex, EplLim, EplSir, Premium, Wage, Sublim, SubmissionId FROM EPL WHERE SubmissionId =" + x;
                    using (SqlCommand epcmd = new SqlCommand(epl, EplConn))
                    {
                        SqlDataReader epdr = epcmd.ExecuteReader();
                        epdr.Read();
                        LblEplShowEntity.Text = epdr.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                        LblEplShowTotalEmpl.Text = epdr.GetInt32(1).ToString();
                        LblEplShowCalEmpl.Text = epdr.GetInt32(2).ToString();
                        LblEplShowMichEmpl.Text = epdr.GetInt32(3).ToString();
                        LblEplShowNyEmpl.Text = epdr.GetInt32(4).ToString();
                        LblEplShowNjEmpl.Text = epdr.GetInt32(5).ToString();
                        LblEplShowPrimEx.Text = epdr.GetInt32(6).ToString();
                        LblEplShowLim.Text = epdr.GetInt32(7).ToString();
                        LblEplShowPrem.Text = epdr.GetInt32(8).ToString();
                        LblEplShowWage.Text = epdr.GetInt32(9).ToString();
                        LblEplShowInvestCost.Text = epdr.GetInt32(10).ToString();
                        epdr.Close();
                    }
```

Comment: If you were to take the string representation (aka `epdr["Entity"].ToString()` and call `int.Parse` or `int.TryParse` on it, does it still give the error? What is the actual text being returned in column 1 (index 0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that database column is int or not. For checking DB Null values do

```
LblEplShowEntity.Text = epdr.IsDBNull(0) ? string.Empty : epdr.GetInt32(0).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Null value in your data? That would cause that exception as well. Also, double-check that the field is really defined as an integer and not, e.g., as a floating point number.

Comment: Yeah, no, as I said, the values are there and the field is defined as int.

Answer (score 0):

You should know exact data type for each column in your select statement. For example, if Entity column is of type `BIGINT`, than you'll have `InvalidCastException` if you try to use `reader.GetInt32()`, because you should use `reader.GetInt64()` method instead.

Second, you should treat NULL values separately. You should check reader.IsDBNull(0) or use following code:

```
int? entity = (int?)reader["Entity"];
```

Notice that you could use string indexer for taking data from data reader. This is more readable approach.

EDIT: try to change your select statement to:

```
string epl = @"SELECT CAST(Entity AS INT) AS Entity, Employees, CA, MI, NY, NJ, Primex, EplLim, EplSir, Premium, Wage, Sublim, SubmissionId 
FROM EPL WHERE SubmissionId =" + x;
```